# How discriminate between two arrays?

Tags: javascript

i want to get just the users which not friends

i have two list, friends and users, 
if they are already friends, then the user list should no longer exist

```js
friends = [{
  friend: {
    id: 3,
    name: "tres"
  },
  owner: {
    id: 1,
    name: "uno"
  }
}];

let users = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "uno",
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "dos"
}]

users = users.filter(currentUser =>
  let flag = false, friends.forEach(function(current) {
      if (currentUser.id == current.friend.id) {
        flag = true;
      }
    }
    return flag;
  ));

console.log(users);
```

i can to use FOR in the function FILTER? is correct?

Comment: I think you want to look at [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: @ScottSauyet but i have two arrays

Comment: ... inside your `filter`.  So something like `users.filter(user => friends.every(relationship => relationship.friend.id !== user.id))` or `users.filter(user => !friends.some(relationship => relationship.friend.id === user.id))`, whichever one reads better to you.

Comment: @ScottSauyet your answer is beautifull!!! work perfect

Comment: Great.  The choice between `some` and `every` here is an interesting one.  What you really want is a `none`, but you can simulate it with either `some` or `every`.

Comment: Added an update to my answer discussing the choice of data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your, `friends` array is a list of relationships.  So

```js
{
  friend: {id: 3, name: "tres"},
  owner: {id: 1,  name: "uno"}
}
```

means that user id 1 is friends with user id 3.

So to check through a collection just use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), whichever one reads better:

```js
const friendless = (users, friends) =>
  users.filter(user => !friends.some(relationship => relationship.friend.id === user.id))

let users = [
  {id: 1, name: "uno"},
  {id: 2, name: "dos"},
  {id: 3, name: "tres"}
]

let friends = [{
  friend: {id: 3, name: "tres"},
  owner: {id: 1,  name: "uno"}
},{
  friend: {id: 2, name: "dos"},
  owner: {id: 1, name: "uno"}
}, {
  friend: {id: 3, name: "tres"},
  owner: {id: 2, name: "dos"}
}];


console .log (
  friendless (users, friends)
)
```

(or like this:

```js
const friendless = (users, friends) =>
  users.filter(user => friends.every(relationship => relationship.friend.id !== user.id))
```

### Update

I don't know if you're in control of the structure of `users` and `friends`, but if you are, you might want to reconsider your data structures.  There seems to be a lot of unnecessary duplication in your current approach.

Any of these approaches might clean it up:

#### A

```js
let users = [
  {id: 1, name: "uno"},
  {id: 2, name: "dos"},
  {id: 3, name: "tres"}
]

let friends = [
  {id: 1, friend: 3},
  {id: 1, friend: 2},
  {id: 2, friend: 3},
];
```

#### B

```js
let users = [
  {id: 1, name: "uno"},
  {id: 2, name: "dos"},
  {id: 3, name: "tres"}
]

let friends = [
  [1, 3],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 3],
];
```

#### C

```js
let users = [
  {id: 1, name: "uno", friends: [3, 2]},  // (or `friendIds`)
  {id: 2, name: "dos", friends: [3]},
  {id: 3, name: "tres", friends: []}
]
```

Option C is especially useful for your current question:

```js
const friendless = users => users.filter(u => u.friends.length === 0)
```